# table which has been dropped before - create migration again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Question regarding migration:
I had a table a few months ago called **payment**
then we wrote a migration and dropped it

now I want that **payment** table again

I generated a migration but when I migrate it actually drops and does not create **payments**.

Please, can someone give me direction? TA

Comment: can you post your migration files and your schema?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you dropped your table.

**How Migration Works**

Whenever migration is created, it has its own timestamp & when you run `rake db:migrate`, it will run `up` method (create table in your case) & store timestamp of that migration in `schema_migrations` table.

You can check whether **payments** table present or not in your database by using following,

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'payments'
```

*case* - If you have dropped table not by rails migration (by console or external source), Then `schema_migrations` will not clear timestamp of migration which create `payments` table (running down method can clear timestamp). but adding new migration for creating `payments` table with new timestamp will not affect you.

And if still it does not help, it all depends on what you have written in your 'create payment table' migration file, method invoked inside it must be `change` or `up` (additional info).